# How to add registered symbol in a email subject line

Tags: java, html-email

I need help adding a registered symbol in my email output so when the customer recives the email they see registered symobil next to the first word "FSFS in the subject line.  I tried usinf &reg but it doesnt work.

```
String fullName = profile.getAddress().getFirstName() + " " + profile.getAddress().getLastName();
        String html = b.toString()
        .replace("[insertName]", fullName)
        .replace("[trackingnumber]", claim.getClPicNbr().toString())
        .replace("[MM/DD/YY]", dateNow)
        .replace("[CLAIMID]", claim.getClId().toString());

        email.postMail(recipients, "donotreply@fsfs.com", 
                    "FSFS&reg Insurance Claim Received",** I  need the registered symbol here
                    html);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email is not (always) HTML based, and the entity you are using there is `&reg;` (again, not really for email). You could use the symbol itself or the unicode `\u00AE` by changing this

```
 "FSFS&reg Insurance Claim Received"
```

to

```
 "FSFS® Insurance Claim Received"
```

or

```
 "FSFS\u00AE Insurance Claim Received"
```